# pass scope object's key value form function input angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

pardon me if this is a repeat question and i am still a beginner.

see the code below :

```
$scope.clicked=function(key,value){
    $scope[key]=value;}
```

the above code returns `$scope.key` is undefined or `$scope.key=value` even if i pass any value to key. lets say i call the function using `$scope.clicked('yes','i am yes')` . I want `$scope.yes = 'i am yes';` what i get is `$scope.keys='i am yes';` . how do i achieve what i want.?

Comment: `$scope[key]=value`; should work.

Comment: `$scope.[key]=value` is invalid syntax. Try `$scope[key]=value`

Comment: sorry about that. i was using right syntax in my original code. here i typed wrong.

Comment: $scope.keys='i am yes'; ,is it incorrect too, as there is no variable like keys. And please copy paste the exact code which you are working on.

Comment: Although it's working I have checked it on Jsfiddle.

Comment: sorry about wasting your time. the code is correct. the arguments i passed were undefined, so i got errors and wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.clicked=function(key,value){
    $scope[key]=value;}
```

You are using incorrect Syntax $scope.[key] is wrong. $scope[key] is right.

Comment: sorry about that. i was using right syntax in my original code. here i typed wrong.